# Bootstrap scroll spy does not work at all

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy

Anything I try to change or to add or remove to doesn't work at all. Seems like it's something wrong with the navigation bar itself. I have done exactly like in bootstrap and in a bunch of articles from the internet and still nothing That's the code I have:

```js
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navbar-exe' });


$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
     var $anchor = $(this);
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
   }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
  event.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

```html
<head>
   <title>Comming Soon...</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
   <link href="js/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="js/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-exe">
    <!--Navigation bar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-defaul navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar-exe">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-2">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand logo page-scroll" href="#Home">WebArtist</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbar-collapse-2">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
                    <li>
                        <a href="#Home" class="page-scroll">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#About" class="page-scroll">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#Contact" class="page-scroll">Contact</a>
                    </li>  
                </ul> 
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav><!-- /.navbar -->
    <!--Navigation bar ends here-->
```

What It is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `"ReferenceError: $ is not defined"` , most of the time it's reference issue.
Your jquery library is not properly referred or loaded
**Check whether you reference is correct, check your path and file name.**

Comment: I have more jquery code on my web page and it works perfectly. I am sure the library is fine.

Comment: just to clarify why do you use like this `var $anchor = $(this);`. May be this is the issue.. `$` mark in-front of anchor..

Comment: because `$` means jQuery. You can't use it in your variable at the start. It might cause you the error. Remove that '$' mark and check.

Comment: The problem is not that. I just created a new -test page and added the code to a simple bootstrp menu from their website and everything works, after I added my menu(which is bootstrap as well) and it doesn't work. Maybe the problem is the navigation itself and the styles I added on top of it?

Comment: I am not sure, did you try removing that `$' mark and checked? can you give the link, then only i can have idea about where it might went wrong

Comment: Problem solved! The problem was in one missing letter, more precisely the letter T from navbar-default. Funny, but I spent half of my day solving this. God bless, bootstrap..Thx for your attention anyways!

Comment: LOL, Happy that you figure it out  :)